# Rails chartkick pie chart grouping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, highcharts, chartkick

I'm trying to display 2 attributes from a `Run` model inside a pie chart.

In the rails console, I can easily do

```
Run.group(:name, :available_tickets).count, library: {pieSliceText:'label'} %>
```

getting the following output:

```
{["First run", 498]=>1, ["Runnnn", 200]=>1, ["Second Run", 1100]=>1}
```

But when calling this with chartkick like:

```
<%= pie_chart Run.group(:available_tickets, :name).count %>
```

I'd get no output.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you get when trying in console: `Run.group(:available_tickets, :name)` ? Note that, Highcharts requires (by default) format as `[name, value]`, not `[value, name]`. You can change that (only if this is the case) by using [pie.keys](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.pie.keys).